# MPV | Is it possible start mpv with the last quit file or playlist already loaded

Tags: mpv

I Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to quit `mpv` so that the next time I play it, it will start from when I left.

But I should first go to that folder and select the file (`mpv file.mpv`) or files (`mpv *.mp4`)

Is it possible to give some option to `mpv` while starting so that it automatically picks up the last exited file or playlist?

Comment: I only no option `mpv --playlist=/full/path/to/textfile-playlist` you can use find to look for your mp4 files and rediredt the output to a file, and use it as mpv playlist..